# Get Youtube title from youtube without developer/api key

Tags: php, api, youtube

Since april 2015 the old youtube api v2 is deprecated.

I used this link to get the youtube title, which worked pretty good:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/video_id?v=2

instead of the title i get now the following link:

https://youtube.com/devicesupport

Now the recommend to use the v3. To use this api, i have to generate a developer/api key.

Is this really necessary just to get the youtube title of video?

Is there another way to get the title without that key?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, it parses the title and echo's it back out -

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$id);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
echo $ytarr['title'];
```

just have to assign the $id to your video id

It appears to not work for most tracks -- YT returns a restriction error

Comment: Be aware that this sort of scraping is against the YouTube TOS. You may find your IP blocked from accessing it, or they may present a captcha after a while.

Comment: Worked before. But not now.